# Swagger-YAML Bad Mapping entry in my bundle

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

I really don't know what to do here because I am new with YAML

I am getting an error of bad mapping on the following YAML code. Can anyone assist me with this?

Thanks,
Darko

```
 /Bundle/{Bundleid}:
get:
  tags:
  - "Bundle"
  summary: "Get Bundle by Id"
  description: "This endpoint displays bundle details"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "Bundleid"
    in: "path"
    description: "This is unique identifier of the bundle"
    required: true
    type: "string"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"

    400:
      description: "Invalid status value"

delete:
  tags:
  - "Bundle"
  summary: "Delete Bundle by Id"
  description: "Delete Bundle by id"
  operationId: "deleteBundle"
  produces:
  - "application/json"
  parameters:
  - name: "Bundleid"
    in: "path"
    description: "ID of the order that needs to be deleted"
    required: true
    type: "integer"
    minimum: 1.0
    format: "int64"
  responses:
    200:
      description: "successful operation"
      schema:
        type: "array"
        items:
          $ref: "#/definitions/Bundle"
    400:
      description: "Invalid ID supplied"
    404:
      description: "Order not found"
```

Error msg that i am receiving.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the `get` operation, remove `schema` from the path parameter definition. In OpenAPI 2.0, non-body parameters use `type`, not `schema`:

```yaml
      parameters:
      - name: "Bundleid"
        in: "path"
        description: "This is unique identifier of the bundle"
        required: true
        # schema:                           # < -- remove this
        #   $ref: "#/definitions/Bundleid"  # < -- remove this
        type: "string"
```

2) In the `delete` operation, change the parameter name `name: BundleId` to `name: Bundleid` with lowercase `id` so that it matches the spelling used in the path - `/Bundle/{Bundleid}`. Parameter names are case-sensitive!

Comment: After I removed the schema fixed the things that you point out I still got the error Helen :(

Comment: @DarkoTodorovski Please edit your question and post your complete definition. The remaining errors are likely somewhere else.

Comment: What's the new error message after the edits? Please make sure your identation is correct - `get` and `delete` should be indented to the right of the `/Bundle/{Bundleid}`.